# How to save the output of a function with user input

Tags: python, function

I have the following code that returns the mean punctuation of a given array of texts. Is there a way to save the output of that function with different inputs? So for 'train_input' as myinput it should give me the callable variable train_input_punct and for 'test_input' as myinput it should create the callable variable test_input_punct. Is there a way to do this?

```py
def interpunktion(myinput):
    punctuation_test = []
    characters_test = []

    count = lambda l1, l2: len(list(filter(lambda c: c in l2, l1)))


    for sentence in myinput:
        characters_test.append(count(sentence, string.ascii_letters))
        punctuation_test.append(count(sentence, string.punctuation))


    # durchschnittliche Punktuation pro Tweet

    mean_punct = [int(p) / int(c) for p,c in zip(punctuation_test, characters_test)]

    punct_test_array = np.hstack(mean_punct)

    punct_test_array = np.reshape(punct_test_array, myinput.shape)

    return punct_test_array
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. Do you mean `train_input_punct = lambda: interpunktion(train_input)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use some kind of data structure, like a dictionary, so that you can label the value using 'train_input' or 'test_input' as keys.

```
myinput = {
    "train_input": "some training input",
    "test_input": "some testing input"
}

result = interpunktion(myinput)
```

Then in your function, you would just have some kind of conditional statement to determine which method you use to process the data.

```
def interpunktion(myinput):
    for input_type, input_value in myinput.items():
        if (input_type == "train_input"):
             # do some train input stuff
        elif (input_type == "test_input"):
             # do some test input stuff
     # ...
```

You don't have to use a dictionary exactly, could work passing in tuples, lists, whatever. But I think you'll need to pass in some sort of identifier with your data that states whether it's test or train input.

Hope that helps! :)